# SequelizeConnectionError: read UNKNOWN

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

SequelizeConnectionError: read UNKNOWN

I'm encountering a "SequelizeConnectionError: read UNKNOWN" error when attempting to establish a connection to a YugabyteDB database using Deno and Sequelize. I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue.

Details of the Problem:

1. Database and Dialect: I'm trying to connect to a YugabyteDB database and have configured Sequelize with the appropriate dialect, which is "postgres."
2. Database Port: I've confirmed that the database is configured to listen on the port specified in my Sequelize configuration.
3. SSL Configuration: My Sequelize configuration includes SSL options, and I've verified that the CA certificate file (root.crt) exists and is valid. The file path to the CA certificate is correct in my configuration.
4. Reject Unauthorized: I've set rejectUnauthorized: true in my Sequelize configuration, indicating that YugabyteDB should be using SSL. The database is configured to accept SSL connections with certificate verification.
5. Database Host: The DB_HOST environment variable is correctly set to the host where YugabyteDB is running, and I've double-checked the IP address or hostname.
6. Network and Firewall: I've ensured that there are no network or firewall issues that could block the connection to YugabyteDB. The necessary ports are open and accessible.
7. Sequelize and Deno Versions: I'm using Sequelize with Deno and want to ensure compatibility. I plan to update both Sequelize and Deno to their latest versions to address any compatibility issues.
8. Error Handling: In my code, I've implemented error handling to catch and log any errors during the connection process. However, I'm still encountering the "SequelizeConnectionError: read UNKNOWN" error.
9. Debugging: I've added debugging statements to my code to print out the values of important variables and settings during the connection process. This hasn't provided specific insights into the issue.

Request for Assistance:

I'm seeking guidance and assistance in resolving this connection issue. Any insights, suggestions, or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Error Stack]

i already follow yugabyte setup documentation for nodejs

fyi: the same error also happen in cockroachdb